# Jasmine TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'install')

Tags: javascript, maven, frontend, jasmine, thymeleaf

I am on a Java maven project in the back side and the front is in Thymeleaf for a web application.

I want to set up a test framework and for that I chose Jasmine.

I have a problem with the tests of Ajax functions. During the execution of my tests, it does not recognize **`Jasmine.Ajax.`** and **`option.success()`**.

My **pom.xml** file:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasmine</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasmine-jquery</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasmine-ajax</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

My function Ajax:

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/my-data-endpoint",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(myVariable); 
        console.log(data); 
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Error fetching data");
      }
    });
  }
```

Here is my test file on my function:

```
describe("getData", function() {
   beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.Ajax.install();
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    jasmine.Ajax.uninstall();
  });

  it("should fetch data from endpoint", function(done) {
    spyOn(window, 'getData').and.callFake(function(options) {
      options.success({ foo: "bar" }); 
    });

    getData(); //call the Ajax function

    var request = jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent();
    expect(getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(request.url).toBe("/my-data-endpoint");
  });
});
```

The error returned:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'install')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'install')
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8234/spec/gestion-commentaireSpec.js:3:18)
    at attemptSync (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:1886:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:1874:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:1859:10)
    at Spec.queueRunnerFactory (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:697:35)
    at Spec.execute (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:359:10)
    at Object.fn (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:2479:37)
    at attemptAsync (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:1916:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:1871:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:1859:10)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'success')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'success')
    at http://localhost:8234/spec/gestion-commentaireSpec.js:13:15
    at SpyStrategy.exec (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:2052:19)
    at spy (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:194:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8234/spec/gestion-commentaireSpec.js:15:5)
    at attemptSync (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:1886:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:1874:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:1859:10)
    at Spec.queueRunnerFactory (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:697:35)
    at Spec.execute (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:359:10)
    at Object.fn (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:2479:37)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uninstall')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uninstall')
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8234/spec/gestion-commentaireSpec.js:7:18)
    at attemptSync (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:1886:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:1874:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:1859:10)
    at Spec.queueRunnerFactory (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:697:35)
    at Spec.execute (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:359:10)
    at Object.fn (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:2479:37)
    at attemptAsync (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:1916:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:1871:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/jasmine.js:1859:10)
```

Jasmine error:

> [image: Jasmine error]